# Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' (using FFTW and Magick++)

Tags: imagemagick, fftw, libpng

I tried to get FFTW and ImageMagick installed in remote server which I have **NO** root access. I reference [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/install-development-files-locally-to-build-on-system-without-root-access) and add following lines to my `bashrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/usr/bin  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/usr/lib  
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:~/usr/include  
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:~/usr/include
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:~/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

For **FFTW** installation, I ran command

`./configure --prefix=/home/foo/usr --enable-openmp` `make` `make install`

For **libpng** and **ImageMagick**, I ran command

`./configure --prefix=/home/foo/usr` `make` `make install`

To compile,

`g++ main.cpp -o main 'Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs' 'pkg-config fftw3 --libs' -Wall`

Compilation is succeed but following error appear when trying to run the program

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorMissingDelegate'
  what():  Magick: no decode delegate for this image format PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501`

I got `DELEGATES bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib` when i ran `convert -list configure`

Any one can help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem! Even thought delegate has **png** in the list but I look back to the log when doing ./configure, the result of **--with-png** is **no**. Since I put libpng at `/usr`, the correct command is `./configure --prefix=/home/foo/usr LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/usr/lib' CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/usr/include'`